# How to put condition on post build actions?

Tags: hudson, jenkins, hudson-plugins, jenkins-plugins, hudson-api

I have job A and B.

Commit will be polled by job A and build is happening on Job B. So I did promoted plugin for email ext after completion of job B to send email from job A.

I have some periodic schedule task which run on job B itself. That case I needed to configure email triggering.
my problem is if i configure email for job B itself and promoted plugin email ext also..so when commit comes to job A. It will send email from promotion plugin + email I configured for job B. Here two email will trigger for commit job.

So I want to put condition on job B email notification?

Somebody please suggest a plugin that serve my purpose.

Comment: Please rephrase the question - it is not clear which job is calling which, how or why.

Comment: job B is being called by job A.After completion of build, based on success or failure job A should trigger email notifcation..So for job A it is doing two email triggering, one from commiters build and other from nightly build(job B). How can restrict email triggering using plugin? I want to know which plugin i can use for checking condition for postbuild action?

Comment: Please see my answer to your other question - I think they are related: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/11639144/1390251]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not really clear on what is being asked here, but take a look at the [Email-ext](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin) plugin and the [Text-finder](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Text-finder+Plugin) plugin. They may help you.